# Line-height not precisely centers vertically with Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

```
<div id="submitHolder">
    <input type="submit" value="">
</div>

#submitHolder {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    line-height: 124px;
    text-align: center;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    background-image: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/button/256/Button-Next-icon.png");
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 0 none;
    height: 44px;
    width: 194px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BLPE7/4/

as you can see, it is precisely centered vertically with firefox, but not with chrome. How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use padding. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/tDj2U/1/

```
#submitHolder {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    /*line-height: 124px;*/
    padding: 40px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    background-image: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/button/256/Button-Next-icon.png");
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 0 none;
    height: 44px;
    width: 194px;
}
```

Comment: Padding is the way I work around this issue in Google Chrome aswell.

Answer (score 3):

That problem seems to occur because your submit button has an empty value – looks like chrome messes something up with the line-height then. Once I give it a value, and if it’s even just a space character (and therefor still not visible), the problem disappears:

```
<input type="submit" value=" ">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BLPE7/9/

Comment: +1 this is the reason. padding and positioning tricks, are just hacks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is such problem for chrome with big `line-height` values. I solve this problem in your case by [adding](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/BLPE7/8/) position absolute/relative and margin centering:

```
#submitHolder {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    height: 124px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    background-image: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/button/256/Button-Next-icon.png");
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 0 none;
    height: 44px;
    width: 194px;
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -22px 0 0 -97px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/BLPE7/11/

Add `vertical-align:middle` to your input control.